# NIST Standard for Advanced Encryption Standard Algorithm

Tags: aes, rijndael, nist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantage of AES(Rijndael) over Twofish and Serpent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/advantage-of-aesrijndael-over-twofish-and-serpent)

What is the reason of **NIST** why **Rijndael** choose as the **Advanced Encryption Standard**

Comment: See NIST's report here: http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/round2/r2report.pdf

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/advantage-of-aesrijndael-over-twofish-and-serpent

Comment: It looks like you question is answered in the post linked to by CodesInChaos. So, I'm going to close your question. If you feel this is incorrect, please update the question with more detail and flag it for moderator attention.